# FeatureLayer SaveEdits failing

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-silverlight-api

I've created a layer which I have bound a DataFeatureForm. Everything is working hunky dory, up to the point where I try to call the layers SaveEdits method in the EditEnded event. When I call this method, the SaveEditsFailed event is raised, returning the following message:

> ESRI.ArcGIS.Client.Tasks.ServiceException:
>   Unable to complete operation

The Feature's layer API is saying it takes all the edit crud stuff when I hit it with a browser. *also* I don't know if it will help, but I am providing the Feature Layer a subset of all the layers Out Fields. Could that also effect this?

Thanks for yoru help!

*EDIT:* I was able to get the HResult from the exception. HResult = -2146233088

Comment: Hi,
Have you an answer for your error ?
May be post your question on ESRI Forum.

Comment: Can you post some sample code? Also, do you have an HRESULT back?

Comment: -1 This should be made as a comment to the question, not an answer.

Comment: Have you checked if anything gets logged in the ArcGIS Server log?

Comment: thanks for the questions. I'm out of the office today. I should be able to try to get this information tomorrow though!

Comment: Is there an innerexception?  If not, what does Fiddler show?

Comment: There is no inner exception. the HResult is -2146233088. where do I find the ArcGIS Server Log? I am very new to the gis world.

Comment: You can use Server Manager to view the log files, or open directly from the log folder, on my 64 bit machine it's here: C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Server10.0\server\user\log

Comment: So I don't have access to the server. I asked our GIS manager, and he said my account does not have edit privileges. would write/update not provide a better error message than what is above? (note: the GIS data manger did not check the logs).